# C# DES ECB Encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, des, ecb

I am having difficulty encrypting something in C#.

I have 3 variables.
First one is a 16 digit hex,lets call it X value I.E 0072701351979990
Second one is also a 16 digit hex value, lets call it Y I.E 3008168011FFFFFF

These two values have to be XOR 'ed to get the key for the DES-ECB encryption.

Thus resulting in 307a66934068666f . Now thus is my keyblock for the encryption.
Then i have this as my datablock,which is 64 bits for encryption 0E329232EA6D0D73

Now i have the following code for encryption this. 
The result of the encryption should be XOR'ed with the datablock again and 
result in a 64bit result. This is not the case.

This is my code for the encryption

```
$ public static string DESEncrypt(string keyBlock,string dataBlock){
        DES desEncrypt = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] keyBlockBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToInt64(keyBlock, 16));
        byte[] dataBlockBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToInt64(dataBlock, 16));
        desEncrypt.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        desEncrypt.Key = keyBlockBytes;
        ICryptoTransform transForm = desEncrypt.CreateEncryptor();
        MemoryStream enecryptedStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(enecryptedStream, transForm, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cryptoStream.Write(dataBlockBytes, 0, dataBlockBytes.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        byte[] encryptedData = new byte[enecryptedStream.Length];
        enecryptedStream.Position = 0;
        enecryptedStream.Read(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
        string enCryptedHex = BitConverter.ToString(encryptedData);

        return enCryptedHex.Replace("-",""); 
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATED QUESTION** 
I have tested the above solution from CodeInChaos. 
It does give me back a 64 bit result. But still there is something wrong.

Here is my updated code.

The keyblock value is abababababababab
and the data block value is 215135734068666F.

The resultant 64 bit result should be XOR'ed with the data block again.

The final answer is suppose to be 414945DD33C97C47 but I get 
288a08c01a57ed3d.

Why does it not come out right?

Here is the specifications in suppliers documentation for the encryption.

Encryption is DEA in accordance with FIPS 46-3, single DES in ECB mode, using a single 64-
bit DES Key with odd parity.

```
$      public static string DESEncrypt(string keyBlock,string dataBlock){
        DES desEncrypt = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] keyBlockBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToInt64(keyBlock, 16));
        byte[] dataBlockBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToInt64(dataBlock, 16));
        desEncrypt.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        desEncrypt.Key = keyBlockBytes;
        desEncrypt.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        ICryptoTransform transForm = desEncrypt.CreateEncryptor();
        MemoryStream enecryptedStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(enecryptedStream, transForm, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cryptoStream.Write(dataBlockBytes, 0, dataBlockBytes.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        byte[] encryptedData = enecryptedStream.ToArray();
        string enCryptedHex = BitConverter.ToString(encryptedData);
        enCryptedHex = enCryptedHex.Replace("-", "");
        long iDeaEncrypt = Convert.ToInt64(enCryptedHex, 16);
        long iDataBlock = Convert.ToInt64(dataBlock, 16);
        long decoderKey = iDeaEncrypt ^ iDataBlock;
        string decKeyHex = Convert.ToString(decoderKey, 16);
        return decKeyHex;
    }
```

Comment: "Now i have the following code for encryption this. The result of the encryption should be XOR'ed with the datablock again and result in a 64bit result. This is not the case." What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the padding to `PaddingMode.None`:

```
desEncrypt.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
```

But you should really think hard, if DES and ECB is really what you want.

---

b.t.w.

```
byte[] encryptedData = new byte[enecryptedStream.Length];
encryptedStream.Position = 0;
encryptedStream.Read(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
```

can be replaced by:

```
encryptedData = encryptedStream.ToArray();
```

Comment: Hey Man ! Thank you very much. This worked 100%. The result of the encryption is now a 64 bit result. Its not my decision to be using DES and ECB. It is the hardware for which i am generating stuff that uses this encryption. But only in some of the old hardware. The new ones doesn't use this. Thanks for the BTW aswell.

Comment: After i have tested everything and compare to the guides resultant values it doesn't match. 

These are the test values they gave me. The datablock is 215135734068666F and the keyblock is abababababababab . 

The resultant encryption is then XOR'ed with the origanal datablock. 

The final result that I am suppose to get is 414945DD33C97C47 . But I get 288a08c01a57ed3d

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is necessary to set DES Provider to use the FIPS 46-3 Standard so that the DEA uses the permutation tables etc. specified in FIPS 46-3.  Unfortunately I’m also struggling with this same issue.